# Shake to open view modally

Tags: iphone, modal-dialog, shake, motion

I have my 'shake' working fine (using motionEnded), based off of Apple's GLPaint code. When the user shakes the device (running 3.0 and up) I want to open a view controller modally using presentModalViewController.

In my appdelegate I have the notification (as per the GLPaint sample code):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shakeToOpenHiddenScreen) name:@"shake" object:nil];
```

In my shakeToOpenHiddenScreen I just want to open view 'x' modally but I don't think that my appdelegate will respond to presentModalViewController.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a method on UIViewController, so you should either have access to a saved view controller from your appDelegate, or else set up the notification to call one (addObserver:someVC).

"shake" isn't a standard notification name, so there should be some code elsewhere in your app that posts this notification, presumably also copied from the GLPaint sample.

Answer (score 1):

To use presentModalViewController you have to use it from a UIViewController class, or subclass:

For example:
    //RootViewController.m
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:loginRegView animated:YES];

You can way around this problem by defining a navigation controller into your app delegate:

```
//yourApp_comAppDelegate.h
UINavigationController *nav;
...
@property(nonatomic,retain) UINavigationController *nav;
```

and synthesize it

```
@syntetize nav;
```

To use presentModalViewController you have to use it from a UIViewController class, or subclass:

For example:

```
//RootViewController.m
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:loginRegView animated:YES];
```

You can way around this problem by defining a navigation controller into your app delegate:

```
//yourApp_comAppDelegate.h
UINavigationController *nav;
...
@property(nonatomic,retain) UINavigationController *nav;
```

synthesize it

```
//yourApp_comAppDelegate.m
@synthesize nav;
```

and now you can use the method:

```
//yourApp_comAppDelegate.m
[nav presentModalViewController:yourView animated:YES];
```

but, first you have to assign it somewhere, i will do it in the RootViewController

```
//RootViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
app = (yourApp_comAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    app.nav = self.navigationController
}
```

It should work, let me know :)

Comment: You should edit this to remove the repeated text.  Also, a nave controller is no more useful for this purpose than any other view controller, and there should ideally be a view controller called from the app delegate in any app.